# Smooth look_at() in Godot

Tags: godot, gdscript

I am working in GDScript, and I'm trying to get the player to aim their weapon in the direction of the mouse cursor. The `look_at()` function is great, but it's not the smooth movement I'm looking for.

So, instead I've been experimenting with the `lerp()` math operation to make it smooth... but its **very jittery and buggy movement** which is obviously not ideal.

```
func _process(delta):

        rotation_degrees =  lerp(rotation_degrees,rad2deg(get_angle_to(get_global_mouse_position())),aim_speed)
```

See the image of my code [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLK6B.png).

How to resolve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to LERP between 2 angles going the longest route or path in Godot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68875814/how-to-lerp-between-2-angles-going-the-longest-route-or-path-in-godot)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use`_physics_process()` instead of `_process()`

`_process` runs at the fastest possible rate whenever it gets the CPU. That makes it jittery. It is not ideal for player movements since you will need consistency in your frames.

`_physics_process()` is consistent as it is frame independent and is ideal for player movement.

if you want more details I recommend you check this video by [Godot Tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eTBA33tJn9I)

Btw `look_at()` should work just fine :)