# Rotate self between an arc on the local axis Godot

Tags: random, rotation, local, godot, gdscript

I have a node which fires a bullet, but I want to randomly rotate it a little so that certain guns are unpredictable. Specifically, I want to rotate it on the X and Y axes between a -2.5 - 2.5 degree arc on the local axis. I've tried `rotation.x = rand_range(-2.5, 2.5 * PI)` and `rotation.y = rand_range(-2.5, 2.5 * PI)`, but these seem to rotate the node on the global X and Y axes. How should I rotate the bullet emitter node locally between an arc? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to LERP between 2 angles going the longest route or path in Godot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68875814/how-to-lerp-between-2-angles-going-the-longest-route-or-path-in-godot)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: Spawn your bullet

Step 2: Give it the rotation of the parent object

Step 3: To that rotation *add* you random rotation

Step 4: Shoot